# Queries em asp.net mvc com entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou iniciando um projeto em **ASP.NET MVC 5** com **Entity Framework 6**, junto com estudos em mvc. Isso para ter um melhor aprendizado, e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida.

No *controller* tenho o método *Index*, que literalmente retorna um "`select * from usuario`" do banco de dados:

```
// GET: Usuario 
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    return View(db.usuario.ToList()); 
}
```

A minha dúvida, o qual não consegui encontrar, ou talvez por não estar procurando de forma adequada, é o que eu faço se eu necessito de uma querie específica? Por exemplo "`select * from usuario where status = 'ativo'`". Como eu configuro essa querie?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basicamente usando métodos de extensão (ou no inglês, *Extension Methods*). [A lista completa deles está aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable_methods(v=vs.100).aspx), mas procure usar o link como referência, depois de ter dominado o aspecto geral de como escrever um comando completo.

Vou dar alguns exemplos equivalentes, bem como explicações que sejam pertinentes para o entendimento, visto que nunca achei um manual ou tutorial que seja didático o suficiente.

### Como Ler uma Expressão de Predicado (vulgo "expressão lambda")

É uma dificuldade comum programadores que tenham certa senioridade em linguagens orientadas a objeto tenham dificuldade em entender como funciona uma expressão de predicado.

Suponha a expressão do Exemplo 1:

```
db.usuario.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Nome == "Fulano");
```

Isto:

```
x => x.Nome == "Fulano"
```

É uma Expressão de Predicado, e deve ser lida como:

> "Para todo objeto x dentro desta coleção, tal que a propriedade Nome de x seja igual a 'Fulano'."

Ou então outro exemplo (Exemplo 2):

```
db.usuario.Select(x => x.Nome);
```

A expressão:

```
x => x.Nome
```

Deve ser lida como:

> "Para todo objeto x dentro desta coleção, considerar a propriedade Nome de x."

---

### Exemplo 1: `select * from Usuario where Nome = "Fulano";`

Estou supondo que apenas um registro será retornado. Para isso, o método [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.singleordefault(v=vs.100).aspx) satisfaz a necessidade:

```
var resultado = db.usuario.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Nome == "Fulano");
```

---

### Exemplo 2: `select Nome from Usuario;`

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) seleciona alguma propriedade do objeto e devolve um iterador. Esse iterador deve ser logo após transformado em lista para poder ser usado.

```
var resultado = db.usuario.Select(x => x.Nome).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 3: `select Nome, Idade from Usuario;`

Mesmo princípio do exemplo anterior, mas monta-se um objeto anônimo que tenha duas propriedades.

```
var resultado = db.usuario.Select(x => new { x.Nome, x.Idade }).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 4: `select Nome as UsuarioNome, Idade as UsuarioIdade from Usuario;`

Análogo ao exemplo 3, especificando os nomes das propriedades do objeto anônimo.

```
var resultado = db.usuario.Select(x => new { UsuarioNome = x.Nome, UsuarioIdade = x.Idade }).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 5: `select * from Usuario order by Nome;`

Basta usar o método [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.orderby(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var resultado = db.usuario.OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 6: `select * from Usuario order by Nome desc;`

Análogo ao exemplo 5, com outro método, [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.orderbydescending(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var resultado = db.usuario.OrderByDescending(x => x.Nome).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 7: `select * from Usuario order by Nome desc, Idade;`

[`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.thenby(v=vs.100).aspx) é um método cumulativo ao `OrderBy`:

```
var resultado = db.usuario.OrderByDescending(x => x.Nome).ThenBy(x => x.Idade).ToList();
```

Há também a versão [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.thenbydescending(v=vs.100).aspx).

---

### Exemplo 8: `select * from Usuario where Nome like '%Fulano%';`:

Semelhante ao Exemplo 1, apenas trocando o operador de igual por `Contains`:

```
var resultado = db.usuario.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains("Fulano")).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 9: `select * from Usuario group by CategoriaId;`:

Use o método [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var resultado = db.usuario.GroupBy(x => x.CategoriaId).Select(grupo => new { Chave = grupo.Key, Valores = grupo.ToList()}).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 10: `select * from Usuario where UsuarioId in (1, 2, 3);`

```
var listaDeIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3};
var resultado = db.usuario.Where(x => listaDeIds.Contains(x.UsuarioId)).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 11: `select u.* from Usuario u inner join Categoria c ... ;`

O [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.join(v=vs.100).aspx) é um dos operadores mais complicados de entender. Na maioria das vezes, seu uso é desnecessário, mas supondo que seja realmente necessário, vou dar um exemplo supondo que um Usuário possui uma Categoria, e que o *Model* `Usuario` possui uma propriedade chamada `CategoriaId` que é uma chave estrangeira para o *Model* de `Categoria`:

```
var resultado = db.Usuario.Join(db.Categoria,       // A tabela que será unida ao resultado
                                u => u.CategoriaId, // A chave estrangeira da tabela em questão. Nossa tabela em questão é 'Usuario'
                                c => c.CategoriaId, // A chave primária da tabela que será unida
                                // Dados os dois conjuntos, Usuario representado por u e Categoria por c, 
                                // Este argumento produz o retorno do Join, criando um objeto anônimo 
                                // com as propriedades desejadas.
                                (u, c) => new { NomeUsuario = u.Nome, NomeCategoria = c.Nome }).ToList();
```

---

### Exemplo 12: `Aggregate`

[`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549412(v=vs.100).aspx) não tem equivalente em todo e qualquer sistema de banco de dados. É importante explicar o conceito dele antes.

Suponha uma relação de 1 para N, ou então de N para N. No nosso exemplo, suponha que agora o Usuário tenha permissões por tela (vou inventar um *Model* chamado `UsuarioPermissao`, que é uma tabela associativa entre `Usuario` e `Permissao`), que é declarado no *Model* `Usuario` da seguinte forma:

```
public virtual ICollection<UsuarioPermissao> UsuarioPermissoes { get; set; }
```

Pro exemplo fazer sentido, vou combinar o `Aggregate` com outro operador, chamado [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx). `SelectMany` é análogo ao `Select`, mas que serve para um conjunto de objetos.

Suponha que você gostaria de devolver todas as permissões de todos os usuários, sendo as permissões dele em uma única linha, separadas por vírgula (ou então por ponto-e-vírgula, tanto faz). O método `Aggregate` faz isso assim:

```
var resultado = db.Usuario.SelectMany(p => p.UsuarioPermissoes).
                          .Aggregate("",     // String inicial, chamada de 'acumulador'
                                     // A construção abaixo considera 'str' como a String acumulada e 'usuarioPermissao' como o registro atual da iteração
                                     (str, usuarioPermissao) => str + ", " + usuarioPermissao.Permissao.Nome).ToList();
```

Comment: realmente é difícil encontrar manual, ou tutorial didático o suficiente. E cara, sua resposta está excelente e muito melhor do que eu esperava e me atende perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Cara, muito bom.