# Como funciona o método de extensão Aggregate() do Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Há pouco eu vi alguns exemplos que usavam o método `Aggregate()` do `namespace System.Linq`, mas não consegui achar nenhuma boa explicação de como usá-lo.

O que faz este método e como deve-se usá-lo?

Comment: É isto que deseja? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7105505/221800

Comment: Sim @bigown, eu estava com essa pergunta aberta, mas achei que seria uma boa perguntar aqui.

Comment: @jbueno você entende inglês? poderia por favor traduzir pra gente?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [Já respondi isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32391/queries-em-asp-net-mvc-com-entity-framework/32437#32437), mas não especificamente sobre `Aggregate`, então vou isolar a parte da resposta que interessa.
>
> A explicação entá dentro do conceito de uso do Entity Framework, mas você pode usar pra qualquer coisa que use Linq.

[`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549412(v=vs.100).aspx) não tem equivalente em todo e qualquer sistema de banco de dados. É importante explicar o conceito dele antes.

Suponha uma relação de 1 para N, ou então de N para N. No nosso exemplo, suponha que agora o Usuário tenha permissões por tela (vou inventar um *Model* chamado `UsuarioPermissao`, que é uma tabela associativa entre `Usuario` e `Permissao`), que é declarado no *Model* `Usuario` da seguinte forma:

```
public virtual ICollection<UsuarioPermissao> UsuarioPermissoes { get; set; }
```

Pro exemplo fazer sentido, vou combinar o `Aggregate` com outro operador, chamado [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx). `SelectMany` é análogo ao `Select`, mas que serve para um conjunto de objetos.

Suponha que você gostaria de devolver todas as permissões de todos os usuários, sendo as permissões dele em uma única linha, separadas por vírgula (ou então por ponto-e-vírgula, tanto faz). O método `Aggregate` faz isso assim:

```
var resultado = db.Usuario.SelectMany(p => p.UsuarioPermissoes).
                          .Aggregate("",     // String inicial, chamada de 'acumulador'
                                     // A construção abaixo considera 'str' como a String acumulada e 'usuarioPermissao' como o registro atual da iteração
                                     (str, usuarioPermissao) => str + ", " + usuarioPermissao.Permissao.Nome).ToList();
```

> [Agora vou traduzir os exemplos daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105505/linq-aggregate-algorithm-explained), que não envolvam bancos de dados.

## Exemplo 1: Somando números

```
var numeros = new[]{1,2,3,4};
var soma = numeros.Aggregate( (a,b) => a + b);
Console.WriteLine(soma); // resultado: 10 (1+2+3+4)
```

Neste caso, `Aggregate` vai acumulando os resultados de cada soma em `a`, enquanto que `b` é o próximo número da sequência.

- Iteração 1: `a == 1`. `a + 2` (`b == 2`). `a` recebe 3;
- Iteração 2: `a == 3`. `a + 3` (`b == 3`). `a` recebe 6;
- Iteração 3: `a == 6`. `a + 4` (`b == 4`). `a` recebe 10.

## Exemplo 2: Concatenando strings separadas por vírgula

```
var strings = new []{"a","b","c", "d"};
var stringFinal = strings.Aggregate( (a,b) => a + ',' + b);
Console.WriteLine(stringFinal); // resultado: a,b,c,d
```

- Iteração 1: `a == "a"`. `a + ",b"` (`b == "b"`). `a` recebe "a,b";
- Iteração 2: `a == "a,b"`. `a + ",c"` (`b == "c"`). `a` recebe "a,b,c";
- Iteração 3: `a == "a,b,c"`. `a + ",d"` (`b == "d"`). `a` recebe "a,b,c,d";

## Exemplo 3: Multiplicando números usando uma semente

Para entendimento completo, existe um [*overload*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) de `Aggregate` que aceita um parâmetro de semente.

```
var numeros = new []{10,20,30,40};
var valorMultiplicado = numeros.Aggregate(5, (a,b) => a * b); // A semente é 5
Console.WriteLine(valorMultiplicado); //Resultado: 1200000 ((((5*10)*20)*30)*40)
```

## Exemplo 4: Definindo um *delegate*

Suponha que você esteja reimplementando o exemplo 2 e queira colocar uma lógica mais robusta. Há uma forma do `Aggregate` que pode ser usada declarando um *delegate* da seguinte forma:

```
var strings = new []{"a","b","c", "d"};
var stringFinal = strings.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a,b) => {
    if (a.Length > 0)
        a.Append(",");
    a.Append(b);
    return a;
});
Console.WriteLine(stringFinal);
```