# Localizar dados específicos dentro de uma Lista

Tags: c#

Tenho um `List<Class>` originado a partir de uma classe. As propriedades da classe são:

```
datetime DataCotacao
double ValorCotação
double FatorDiario
```

Seguem os dados cadastrados para exemplo:

```
Data      FatorDiario
04/12/17   1,02077
05/12/17   1,03006
06/12/17   1,04563
07/12/17   1,03328
```

Gostaria de efetuar uma lógica que a partir de uma condição em que com dois parâmetros de uma dataInicial e uma dataFinal, por exemplo:

05/12/17 e 07/12/2017, a lista retornasse os valores de 1,03006, 1,04563 e 1,03328 e com estes, eu efetuasse a multiplicação nessa ordem:

```
1º iteração: 1,03006
2º iteração: 1,03006 * 1,04563 = resultado em 1,0770616
3º iteração: 1,0770616 * 1,03328 = resultando em 1,112906
```

E exatidão dos valores aqui é o menos importante. Gostaria mesmo de saber a lógica que eu deveria implementar para chegar neste resultado final (1,112906) levando todas as condições apresentadas acima.

Comment: estrutura de dados lineares - lista simplesmente encadeada é o tipo de estrutura que está sendo usada, pode tentar pesquisar sobre que certamente encontra a resposta, ou pode popular um dataset e usar a estrutura de dados dele para puxar os valores.

Comment: @cabarbosa78 Seu intuito é chegar apenas no valor final ou obter todas as multiplicações até chegar no final?

Comment: @LINQ, a questão justamente é que o resultado final é a composição destas multiplicações com base nos fatores diários encontrados na lista no range de datas. Não sei se consegui te esclarecer..

Comment: Conseguiu sim, mas o que eu quero saber é: Você precisa saber cada um destes valores separadamente ou precisa apenas do último?

Comment: Preciso somente o resultado final (último).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para o seu problema pode ser divida em duas partes distintas.

A primeira parte é criar um filtro para obter apenas os registros que estejam dentro do intervalo de data que foi especificado por você.

Isso pode ser feito usando o método de extensão [**`Where`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) do LINQ.

A segunda parte da solução consiste em "acumular" os resultados de cada um dos itens que foram filtrados, de forma que o resultado seja a multiplicação de todos eles. Isso pode ser feito com o método [**`Aggregate`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) também do LINQ. Você pode ver mais sobre este método na pergunta [Como funciona o método de extensão Aggregate() do Linq?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90925/18246)

Perceba que usar o método **`Aggregate`** também vai possibilitar que você salve todos os valores acumulados. A variável `a` faz o trabalho do acumulador, então se for preciso discriminar cada um destes valores é só fazer com que os valores de `a` sejam salvos em algum lugar.

Exemplo em código:

```
var res = _lista.Where(model => model.Data >= inicio && model.Data <= fim)
                .Select(model => model.FatorDiario)
                .Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jWG1dT)</sup>

Código completo, só rodar:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    private static List<Model> _lista = new List<Model>
    {
        new Model { Data = new DateTime(2017, 12, 04), FatorDiario = 1.02077M },
        new Model { Data = new DateTime(2017, 12, 05), FatorDiario = 1.03006M },
        new Model { Data = new DateTime(2017, 12, 06), FatorDiario = 1.04563M },
        new Model { Data = new DateTime(2017, 12, 07), FatorDiario = 1.03328M }
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime inicio = new DateTime(2017, 12, 05);
        DateTime fim = new DateTime(2017, 12, 07);

        var s = _lista.Where(model => model.Data >= inicio && model.Data <= fim)
                      .Select(model => model.FatorDiario)
                      .Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public DateTime Data;
    public decimal FatorDiario;
}
```

Comment: @LINK, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou implementar e ver como fica o resultado. Ficando ok, eu retorno para concluir. Valeu!

Comment: @LINK, a lógica funcionou em meu contexto, muito obrigado!